# Compiling OpenCV with Contrib and C++11 Support?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, ubuntu, cmake

I want to compile opencv from source on ubuntu 16.04.
I already did this  successfully a couple of times before.
I am following this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) from pyimagesearch.
Normally this works very well, but this time I am getting the following error for the contrib module text.

> [ 27%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_text_RELEASE.gch In file
>
> included from /usr/include/c++/5/cinttypes:35:0,
>
> from /usr/local/include/tesseract/host.h:30,
> from /usr/local/include/tesseract/serialis.h:26,
> from /usr/local/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:37,
> from /home/rvq/github/opencv-3.2.0/build/modules/text/precomp.hpp:51:
>
> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file
> requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard.
> This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
> compiler options.  #error This file requires compiler and library
> support \   ^
>
> [ 27%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_saliency

Does somebody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `-D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \` to CMake command resolved the issue.

Complete CMake Command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/github/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
    -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Comment: @GuySoft What did the trick for me was setting `-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON` as I was previously trying to compile it with `-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF`. I don't see how those things are connected, just my sheer experience.